# Data conversion in R

Tags: r

The data frame I have is

```
         rows     probes
            3    244903_at
            4    244904_at 
            6    244906_at
            12   244912_at
            13   244913_at
            20   244920_s_at
            21   244921_s_at
            23   244923_s_at
            26   244924_at
```

and wanted to convert it as follows:

```
     structure(c(3L, 4L, 6L, 12L, 13L, 20L, 21L, 23L, 24L, 26L), .Names = c("244903_at", 
        "244904_at", "244906_at", "244912_at", "244913_at", "244920_s_at", 
        "244921_s_at", "244923_s_at", "244924_at"))
```

I tried using

```
            df<-as.vector(df)
```

but it gives me only a character vector and not a named integer one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, you want to get the `rows` column of your data frame and give it `probes` as the names?

```
x <- setNames(df$rows, df$probes)
```

or

```
x <- structure(df$rows, names=as.character(df$probes))
```